# JSF is not printing the numbers

Tags: java, jsf

am trying to print these list of numbers below values in my page but these values are not printing in my jsf page, the rest of the tags in the page prints perfectly, i looked in my controller class whether the list has elements are not it has the values as [1,2,3,4] and I looked in the view source but these values are not available in the view source. can some one please let me know where am doing wrong. Thanks!!!

```
<h:dataTable value="#{pagination.pagesList}" var="page">
  <h:outputText value="#{page}"></h:outputText>
</h:dataTable>
```

Backing Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < plth; i++) {
            pageInt[i] = ++pageno1;
            pagesList = Arrays.asList(pageInt);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column to your table:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{pagination.pagesList}" var="page">
  <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{page}"></h:outputText>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Update:

So you have a `List<Integer>`? This might be the problem because list elements are addressed by an integer index. As far as I know the list elements for `h:dataTable` have to be beans.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but No Luck :-(

Comment: Could you add the code of your backing bean (at least the relevant parts)?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < plth i++) {
   pageInt[i] = ++pageno1;
   pagesList = Arrays.asList(pageInt);
   
  }

Comment: but this working when am trying to access through the controller class direclty, but not direclty through the backingbean list...

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you create the list with every iteration and not after completion of the loop? Do you have getter/setter for your list?

Comment: So you have a List<Integer>? This might be the problem because list elements are addressed by an integer index. As far as I know the list elements for h:dataTable have to be beans.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing `<h:column>`, as rightly mentioned by Matt, you've another problem here:

```
pagesList = Arrays.asList(pageInt)
```

This creates a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>`. If you have had used [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) properly (so if you have *really* used `List<Integer>` instead of `List` or `List<?>`), then you should already be trapped on this mistake by a compilation error.

Your current list has only one item which is an `int[]`. When you print it plain as an item inside the JSF datatable, it'll look something like

```
[I@1234567
```

Where the part after `@` is the hashcode of the `int[]` object instance.

Your code makes at its own very little sense, so it is hard to give a suitable answer. I think you made another mistake by attempting to convert it to a list *inside* the loop instead of *after* the loop (so the list get overridden everytime until it holds the converted list of the last iteration). This is unnecessary.

But to the point, to convert an `int[]` to a `List<Integer>`, you need to loop over it again after you have filled the `pageInt`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < plth; i++) {
    pageInt[i] = ++pageno1;
}

pagesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int page : pageInt) {
    pagesList.add(page);
}
```

Or, maybe better, get rid of `pageInt` altogether and use `pagesList` all the way:

```
pagesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < plth; i++) {
    pagesList.add(++pageno1);
}
```